# What is the best way for feature extraction form text in Python

Tags: python, pandas, text, machine-learning

Lets say I have a row in a series in python containing the values `A, B, C, A`.
I can apply count vectorizer to it but count vectorizer would return `A -2, B-1, C-1`. What I want is the following output `A-1, B-1, C-1`. It should only see that A is present and return 1 for it.  How can I do that?

How can I get the total number of unique values inside the series. Like if the second row has only `B, D`. Then it should return `4`.

Lets say the name of the series is `df['a']`.

1st row = `A,B,C,A` Desired output-`A,B,C`

2nd row = `B,D,B` Desired output-`B,D`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the unique items of a series by:

```
df['a'].unique()
```

Additionally, you can use `Series.value_counts`:

```
df['a'].value_counts()
```

This will return the count of all the unique values in the series.

Comment: This would not solve the problem. It would just give the answer as 2.